# Find the smallest circumference of a figure containing n squares

Tags: algorithms, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

So there's a figure which contains n squares of 1 x 1, and I have to find the smallest circumference possible. I don't know if there's an algorithm behind this, I've been stuck on this for two hours but can't figure a working algorithm.

I do know that the smallest circumference of four squares is 8, of 11 is 14 and 200 is 58. If anyone could give me a hint on where to begin, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: By circumference, do you mean perimeter?

Comment: Yes sorry it's unclear

Comment: Are squares required to have integral coordinates? If so this is an integer-valued sequence, which you can look for at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) by inputting the first few terms you know.

Comment: And it is sequence A027709 "Minimal perimeter of polyomino with n square cells" where you will find more information and references. In particular the formula 2*ceiling(2*sqrt(n)) is a "working algorithm".

Comment: How, Jimmy, do you know that the answers for $11$ and $200$ squares is $14$ and $58$?

Comment: You might like to search for "isoperimetry".

Answer (score 1):

Some best known results are shown here: https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP asks about perimeter of the union of squares, not about the smallest circle containing the union.

Comment: I wondered about that, but the value 14 for 11 squares seems to match the circumference in the link.

Comment: Where in the link do you read this? for 11 squares I read "r = 2.214+".

Comment: Multiplying that radius by $2\pi$ gets a circumference that is close to 14, but the OP has now confirmed that he instead meant perimeter.